# How to set Paperclip to process original image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Using Paperclip Gem in a Rails 4 project to attach an image and then clean out all exif data, like this:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    styles: lambda{ |a|
                          { 
                            large:      ['800x', :png],
                            thumb_340:  ['340x340#', :png],
                            thumb_180:  ['180x180#', :png]
                          }
                  },
    convert_options: { all: '-strip' }
```

Problem is, `convert_options` isn't getting called on the original image. What's the best method for reprocessing (or pre-processing) the original to make sure that `'-strip'` gets called?

Comment: Check out this ,
[covert option conditionally][1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221167/conditional-convert-options-paperclip

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
has_attached_file :image,
styles: lambda{ |a|
                      { 
                        original: {convert_options: '-strip'},
                        large:      ['800x', :png],
                        thumb_340:  ['340x340#', :png],
                        thumb_180:  ['180x180#', :png]
                      }
              }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer!

Comment: what's your question? for strip exif data just use this construction. in my case it looks like 
`has_attached_file :media, styles: { original: {convert_options: '-strip'}, thumb: "155x155#" }`
so we have thumb(150x150) and original file with stripped exif due
`convert_options: '-strip'`

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me